# Spark Ar Change Scale of an Object via Script

Tags: javascript, async-await, transform, spark-ar-studio

I am trying to change scale of an object via script. I looked up documentation of spark ar but cannot find an example of how to manipulate scale property of an object via script. I tried something on my code but it did not work.

```
const [object] = await Promise.all([
    Scene.root.findFirst('object')
       ]);
  
const somethingHappened= await Patches.outputs.getBoolean('event');
if(somethingHappened){
  object.Transform.scale.toSignal(0,0); //I have no idea about this line just made up
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation for the Transform property [here](https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/reference/classes/SceneModule.Transform).

You'll see that Transform.scale uses a [PointSignal](https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/reference/classes/ReactiveModule.PointSignal#enums), that's because scale is actually three dimensional: scaleX, scaleY, and scaleZ. To construct a point signal in Spark you can use Reactive.point(scaleX, scaleY, scaleZ).

Here's how you would do it using JS:

```
//define scale as 50%
let scale = .5;

//set the object scale as a point
object.transform.scale = Reactive.point(scale, scale, scale);
```